# Difficulty with finding sum of csv file

Tags: python, csv

Write a function named "csv_sum" that takes a string as a parameter representing the name of a CSV file with 5 columns in the format "int, int, int, int, int" and returns the sum of all the values in the fourth column from the input file. (My code below)

```
import csv
def csv_sum(string):
    with open(string) as f:
        file = csv.reader(f)
        total = 0
        for line in file:
            for number in line[3]:
                total = total + int(number)
    return total
```

I keep getting error on input ['typically.csv']: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: provide sample of csv file.

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?*: Print the `line` to see what you get.

Comment: And print the number.

Comment: How should I go on to solve this problem?

Comment: You're trying to convert the character at position 3 in the line, a dash `-` to an `int`, which python can't interpret

Comment: I think this was a fair question for someone new to python or csv.reader. Since there a 'csv' tag, I think the requester was maybe too focused on 'csv' versus the int conversion.

Comment: What do you mean by a dash to an int?

Comment: Please print the line that contains the `-` sign. We need to see it here so we can reproduce the issue, i.e. to make this a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example (MCVE).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the

```
for number in line[3]:
```

Look for negative numbers in your csv file. The for loop would give two strings for a negative number, i.e. -4 loops '-', '4'. Therefore int('-') is  invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'.

You do not need the extra for number loop. Try the following:

```
for line in file:
    total = total + int(line[3])
```

If you had just tested with print number, I think you would have found the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You were thinking too complicated, `line[3]` are the values themselves. `for number in line[3]` iterates over the individual characters of those values and tries to cast them to `int` which fails for the `'-'` of a negative number:

```
def csv_sum(string):
    with open(string) as f:
        file = csv.reader(f)
        total = 0
        for line in file:
            total = total + int(line[3])
    return total
```

Or shorter, using `sum`:

```
def csv_sum(string):
    with open(string) as f:
        return sum(int(line[3]) for line in csv.reader(f))
```